# How to sort score highest to lowest

Tags: python, sorting

```
def sub_sort(array,low,high):
    key=array[low]
    while low<high:
        while low<high and array[high]>=key:
            high-=1
        while low<high and array[high]< key:
            array[low]=array[high]
            low+=1
            array[high]=array[low]
    array[low]=key
    return low
def quick_sort(array,low,high):
    if low<high:
        key_index=sub_sort(array,low,high)
        quick_sort(array,low,key_index)
        quick_sort(array,key_index+1,high)


score1=int(input(":"))
score2=int(input(":"))
score3=int(input(":"))


sort=[score1,score2,score3]
quick_sort(sort,0,len(sort)-1)
print(sort)
```

This is my code and so far it only sorts the numbers from lowest to highest instead of highest to lowest.

Comment: Do you want a sort function, or do you want to _write_ a sort function?

Comment: Replace the sign in comparisons between array elements and key.

Comment: If all else fails `print(sort[::-1])` ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Ashalynd said, you just need to change the sign when doing the comparisons. The result looks as follows:

```
def sub_sort(array,low,high):
    key=array[low]
    while low<high:
        while low<high and array[high]<=key:
            high-=1
        while low<high and array[high]> key:
            array[low]=array[high]
            low+=1
            array[high]=array[low]
    array[low]=key
    return low

def quick_sort(array,low,high):
    if low<high:
        key_index=sub_sort(array,low,high)
        quick_sort(array,low,key_index)
        quick_sort(array,key_index+1,high)


score1=int(input(":"))
score2=int(input(":"))
score3=int(input(":"))


sort=[score1,score2,score3]
quick_sort(sort,0,len(sort)-1)
print(sort)
```

If you do not need to implement the sorting algorithm on your own, a better solution would be:

```
score1 = int(input(":"))
score2 = int(input(":"))
score3 = int(input(":"))

data = [score1, score2, score3]

print sorted(data, reverse=True)
```